# PHP не изменяется переменная

Tags: php

```
$type_get = $_GET['type'];
    $type_set = $_GET['set'];
    $isSending = "false";

    if ($type_get == "set") {
        $isSending = $type_set;
        echo $isSending." with type ".gettype($isSending);
    }

    else if ($type_get == "get") {
        echo $isSending;
    }
```

Проверял через консоль, что при обращении к этому коду через `type=set&set=true` `isSending` меняется на `true`, но если потом обратиться через `type=get` то переменная по прежнему равна `false`, что-то не понимаю, почему так происходит

Comment: Потому что http - протокол без запоминания состояния.

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь вариант другой, как можно сделать что-то подобное? просто у меня отправка сообщения реализована, и иногда она долго происходит (при загрузке файлов, например), и нужно через ajax проверять состояние, чтобы нельзя было несколько раз одно и то же отправить

Comment: для хранения промежуточных данных есть механизм сессий.